# Haskell to C - Self-defined datatypes

Tags: c, haskell, types

I have the following Haskell datatype:

```
data RegExp sy  = Empty
    | Epsilon
    | Literal   sy
    | Or        (RegExp sy) (RegExp sy)
    | Then      (RegExp sy) (RegExp sy)
    | Star      (RegExp sy)
deriving (Read, Eq)
```

I need to call it from C and I was wondering if anyone has any experience on how to do this? I 've done it with simple datatypes like in this tutorial: http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Calling_Haskell_from_C but I am not sure how to do it since I have a datatype that I have defined myself.

Showing returns a String like shown when following was entered:

```
*Language.HaLex.RegExp> let f = (Or a a)
*Language.HaLex.RegExp> :t f
f :: RegExp Char
*Language.HaLex.RegExp> show f
"'a'+'a'"
*Language.HaLex.RegExp> :t show f
show f :: String
```

Yet when I have the following:

```
simplifyRegExp_hs :: CString -> CString
simplifyRegExp_hs = simplifyRegExp

foreign export ccall simplifyRegExp_hs :: CString -> CString
```

The following error occurs:

```
Simplify.hs:317:21:
    Couldn't match type `RegExp t0'
              with `GHC.Ptr.Ptr Foreign.C.Types.CChar'
    Expected type: CString -> CString
      Actual type: RegExp t0 -> RegExp t0
    In the expression: simplifyRegExp
    In an equation for `simplifyRegExp_hs':
        simplifyRegExp_hs = simplifyRegExp

Simplify.hs:319:1:
    Illegal foreign declaration: requires via-C, llvm (-fllvm) or native code    generation (-fvia-C)
    When checking declaration:
      foreign export ccall "simplifyRegExp_hs" simplifyRegExp_hs
        :: CString -> CString
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Comment: http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/FFI_Introduction

Answer (score 4):

You're claiming to the compiler that `simplifyRegExp` has type `CString -> CString` when it has type `RegExp a -> RegExp a`. You need to first write the function that actually has type `CString -> CString`. This means providing a `Read` instance for your `RegExp` type to go along with the show instance. Once you have that, you can do the following:

```
simplifyRegExp_hs :: CString -> IO CString
simplifyRegExp_hs cs = do s <- peekCString cs
                          let reg = read s :: RegExp <element type>
                          newCString (show reg)
```

If it's not easy to write a `Read` instance for your type, you'll need to marshal the data type into a C struct and provide a conversion from your Haskell type to the C struct in Haskell. This is, in general, the better solution since you don't have to unnecessarily deal with parsers, but if your example is simple enough, the `Read` instance can work as well.